# Problema con Android Studio y Microsoft Azure

Tags: programación-móvil, microsoft, azure-sql

Soy muy novato e igual estoy preguntando una tontería pero allá voy...
Pretendo crear una aplicación en android studio que se conecte a una base de datos SQL y dicha base de datos debe estar en la nube para que varios usuarios puedan acceder de forma simultanea desde diferentes dispositivos, pensaba hacerlo creando una base de datos y servidor SQL en microsoft Azure y mediante los "Mobile services" crear la aplicación en android ya enlazada y empezar a programar.

Mi problema es que la cuenta de estudiante que me he creado no dispone de los mobile services, no los encuentro por ningún sitio y por lo tanto no se cómo enlazar una aplicación android con la base de datos.

Si alguien me puede aportar alguna solución con otra base de datos on line que no sea microsoft azure me vale también.

Gracias por adelantado!!

Comment: 7 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes 2. Revisa el Tour en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour  3. Revisa cómo preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 4. Mira los ingredientes de una buena pregunta en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 5. Toma, quizás te sea de utilidad: https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/azure/using-windows-azure-mobile-services-in-android-applications.htm La interfaz actual ha cambiado y por algún lado ha de estar la opción. 6. Te sugiero que aprendas a crear Web APIs con alguna tecnología y desde las apps móviles, envíes peticiones http a tu WebAPI

Comment: 7. Revisa este tutorial http://fredyfx.com/post/elevando-el-cosmos-con-aspnetcore-2-vuejs-entity-framework-core-2-y-postgresql-parte-5/ quizás te pueda dar un mejor panorama de cómo se trabaja con una api web. Saludos y buena suerte con el desarrollo :D

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias alternativas para servicios de almacenamiento de datos en tiempo real que te pueden servir, partiendo por uno de los mas usados que es [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=es).
Puedes encontrar mas informacion de como empezar en android con Firebase
en https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup/

Otras opciones mas o menos complicadas son Parse, Back4App, y otras de este estilo. Cada uno con planes free con ciertos limites de recursos. Si la aplicacion crece y tiene mucho trafico de datos ya se necesitaria cambiar a un plan avanzado.

Otra opcion es implementar por ti mismo una API REST en algun servicio en linea ya sea Microsoft Azure (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/product-categories/databases/) o alguna otra alternativa en Amazon Web services, o incluso Heroku donde puedes publicar una API REST de manera gratuita (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api).
Luego aprender a implementar consultas mediante HTTP desde android https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple